# add link to content items/data from razor template

Tags: 2sxc

I can add the following lines to crate a direct link to add new items from a razor template

```
@* this will show an "add" button if the current user is an editor *@
@Edit.Toolbar(actions: "new", contentType: "ContentTypeName")
```

Is there a similar way to enable a direct link to the content's items/data if the user is an editor, instead of clicking through the item's toolbar [...] to get to the "table" button/icon.

### UPDATE:

I tried to add the action name 'contentitems' as listed [here](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/blob/master/src/inpage/2sxc._actions.js):

```
 @Edit.Toolbar(actions: "new,contentitems", contentType: "ContentTypeName")
```

But the "table" button was not added.

### SOLUTION:

I used the following code (notice the addition of "more")

```
@Edit.Toolbar(actions: "new, more, contentitems", contentType: "Image")
```

The user has to click through the "..." more button, but that is just fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue as of now is that the additional buttons are in a separate rotation of the menu, so they are not visible. this is not fully implemented, the quickest solution for now is to also add the "more" button, just to be sure you can rotate to the table. sorry :(